# PostgreSQL as OLAP setup

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse, olap, sql-data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

I am trying to setup postgresql to use OLAP benefits as my current OLTP db is no more required, hence i want to move it to OLAP system for genrating reports as there would not be much transactions where as onlny reporting and other warehouse activities only.
#postgresql #OLAP #DWH #RDBMS

i am trying to create a DB for OLAP functionality but seeing no where if there any configuration changes.
My palna to setup ROLAP as my earlier DB was OLTP only i need to switch it too OLAP for reporting etc but very less transactions too.

Comment: Need to know all about OLAP setup for postgresql, any prerequisite and what all configuration needed from DB side . Thanks in advance

Comment: That’s far too general a question. What research have you done into setting up OLAP on postgresql and what specific question do you have based on your research?

Comment: Indeed it is very general , as i am new  in this setup, I know aabout terms used in ROLAP , MOLAP AND HOLAP . Planning to setup as MOLAP but need to know what all configuration would need to do for each of three, appreciate if you can help on making understanding on same.

Comment: Hi - apart from agreeing that this is a general question, you seem to have ignored everything in my previous comment after the first sentence